# Many to many relation with the same table with EF4.3 Code First

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

How to make a configuration with this schema?

```
CREATE TABLE Entity
(
    Id int identity primary key,
    Name nvarchar(30)
)

CREATE TABLE Member
(
    ParentEntityId references Entity(Id),
    ChildEntityId references Entity(Id)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

Model class:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Entity> Parents { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Entity> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Parents)
    .WithMany(e => e.Children)
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("Member");
        m.MapLeftKey("ParentEntityId");
        m.MapRightKey("ChildEntityId");
    });
```